# Align double axis in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to create a plot with a double axis.
The data can be found here below :

```
dput(df)
structure(list(OBS_DATE = structure(c(10957, 11048, 11139, 11231, 
11323, 11413, 11504, 11596, 11688, 11778, 11869, 11961, 12053, 
12143, 12234, 12326, 12418, 12509, 12600, 12692, 12784, 12874, 
12965, 13057, 13149, 13239, 13330, 13422, 13514, 13604, 13695, 
13787, 13879, 13970, 14061, 14153, 14245, 14335, 14426, 14518, 
14610, 14700, 14791, 14883, 14975, 15065, 15156, 15248, 15340, 
15431, 15522, 15614, 15706, 15796, 15887, 15979, 16071, 16161, 
16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 
17075, 17167, 17257, 17348, 17440, 17532, 17622, 17713, 17805, 
17897, 17987, 18078, 18170, 18262, 18353, 18444, 18536, 18628, 
18718, 18809, 18901, 18993, 19083), class = "Date"), Net_operating_surplus_to_value_added = c(36.9656739231445, 
36.8689864882343, 36.6317520083419, 36.8317643474959, 37.6935121500197, 
38.5018034788891, 38.9957638139427, 39.1885608912447, 38.6092136149497, 
38.2770183401821, 38.4489120097893, 38.3537299053262, 38.4156940299523, 
38.137139643167, 37.8894433308562, 37.7064555602493, 37.9839392196746, 
38.3746788684954, 38.6020160570843, 38.8268119307867, 38.5613405710757, 
38.7101242715524, 38.8273476727589, 38.8869873772993, 39.720479442795, 
39.6658712861905, 39.8767955423033, 40.3180414586718, 40.9445739166353, 
41.4504448781142, 42.1689391948721, 42.5475515086736, 42.0065894935759, 
41.8235800428308, 41.0535110327202, 39.3776111728045, 37.2918935656955, 
34.7987917589771, 33.6060430866382, 33.2333240074088, 33.5352650692288, 
34.0870394255266, 34.4296192872216, 34.9379435365405, 35.4951911949687, 
35.5398028603395, 35.5785861381144, 35.0406777120541, 34.4467029671623, 
33.4624900670117, 32.6226354628198, 31.8258664477327, 31.2901452931081, 
31.3585743099158, 31.6843235126606, 32.0760017276417, 32.5304675296323, 
32.5073363450562, 32.6352221514581, 32.7957586698719, 33.3467283704801, 
33.9694837972178, 34.5433408050505, 35.1956294062996, 35.0685963830019, 
35.607294642208, 35.581902998671, 35.7209284106957, 35.9308759449264, 
35.6894948426784, 36.2947609108182, 36.2938680510367, 36.2653856458804, 
36.08587682079, 35.182630097821, 34.6910386509771, 34.5456518897842, 
34.046625027426, 34.2605143927775, 34.2141127409063, 33.1221766349027, 
31.0095937520034, 30.2453076663821, 30.2414563984248, 31.704392011148, 
34.5010174977904, 34.8147384445836, 34.7697905115992, 34.43625109411, 
33.8841955271951), Met_retained_earnings_to_value_added = c(3.65946513678856, 
2.99463238024132, 2.49514650123736, 3.02457398855396, 3.52170627766491, 
3.65874887644949, 3.75035993710115, 4.19023687395792, 5.03705154102929, 
5.57632125508043, 8.2495415198731, 9.1177952075909, 8.39854897090696, 
7.90761699297047, 6.61882380938546, 5.82196030311438, 6.14631242125481, 
6.17680298128492, 6.07542512868537, 6.01032154224047, 5.66854842968337, 
5.47974183094731, 5.26498409983987, 5.0098922839463, 5.5332050888931, 
4.46960255520707, 4.37466881326977, 4.15148205815225, 4.52903352953872, 
4.45114690933355, 5.03266104719299, 4.95052573926497, 3.97052831893563, 
3.50569271340267, 2.44196835732784, 1.5954474561901, 0.389019198525782, 
0.491438385056609, 1.53710358969239, 3.326229908946, 5.04170916975847, 
5.60436479062756, 6.57740686481843, 6.02041199986632, 5.60803794337375, 
5.78906824166877, 4.75880249860857, 5.05756309766792, 4.51410756786046, 
4.34574033479928, 3.45056503904027, 2.77862946386903, 3.39068127274666, 
3.87423424368168, 5.060146724212, 5.59504392224852, 5.94120589707917, 
5.38305476870492, 5.44128431403496, 5.9577367772693, 6.5888030147431, 
7.1133680406906, 7.53087422774044, 8.18386901533204, 8.2264735443145, 
8.95382429921373, 9.51201069521699, 9.5114820156883, 9.64064423866319, 
9.05512739701095, 9.40881852811793, 10.0114821239402, 9.5692691653021, 
9.0906823904455, 8.47113772060278, 7.64711815518838, 8.0943097283881, 
7.77194975031624, 8.04157404171203, 8.3642302611957, 7.11751092092824, 
6.1040017121415, 5.52587902763856, 5.87309706295293, 7.38715617317306, 
10.082162546155, 10.5674522055678, 9.83495111956979, 9.30377793666422, 
6.87773746393322)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -90L
))
```

The following is the code that I am using

```
min_Date <-  as.Date("2021-01-01")  
max_Date <- df$OBS_DATE[length(df$OBS_DATE)]
start_point <-  c(min_Date, max_Date)

chart2 <- plot_ly(x = df$OBS_DATE, y = df$Net_operating_surplus_to_value_added, type = 'scatter',  mode = 'lines', name = "Net operating surplus to value added (LHS)", line = list(color = "#003299") ) %>% 
            
add_trace(y = df$Met_retained_earnings_to_value_added,  name = "Met retained earnings to value added (RHS)", line = list(color = "#FFB400" ), yaxis = "y2") %>% 

layout(barmode = 'relative', barbase = 0, xaxis = list(range = start_point), yaxis = list(range = c(30,44)),  yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right",range = c(0, 14)))
```

In this way I am able to align the axis in the zoomed version of the chart
[image]]

However, when I look at the whole series the grid lines become misaligned.

[image]

```
> min(df$Net_operating_surplus_to_value_added)
[1] 30.24146
> max(df$Net_operating_surplus_to_value_added)
[1] 42.54755

> max(df$Met_retained_earnings_to_value_added)
[1] 10.56745
> min(df$Met_retained_earnings_to_value_added)
[1] 0.3890192
```

What I can do to solve this problem ?

Comment: you need to share a reproducible example of your `df`!

Comment: You can find the df here: https://github.com/AlbertoDeBenedittis/dataSoF/blob/main/margin%26saving.Rdata

Comment: I am sorry, but that's not the right practice. You should share your data within the body of the question. You can do that by running `dput(df)` and sharing the results of that at the bottom of your question. Simply [edit] and add that above.

Comment: It should be fine now .

Comment: I was able to produce your second full image by removing `xaxis = list(range = start_point)` from your code. However, I don't get any mismatched grid lines like in your image. It looks fine in the RStudio viewer and it looks fine when I download the plot as a png.

Comment: Of course I do not have problem when I remove `xaxis = list(range = start_point)`. I would like to keep it so that either with the default (zoomed) view of the chart and the view of the whole series (that I get by double clicking on the zoomed view),  the axes are aligned.

Comment: I've looked at this multiple different ways, I'm unable to get the axes to misalign as shown in your second image. One thing that I notice is that you have the range set, but in your second image, the range shown is not representative of your code. Did you do something other than adding an `xaxis` range to create the first plot? It seems unlikely to be an issue, but do you have the latest version of `plotly`?

Comment: The second image is obtained by double clicking on: when you double click plotly shows the whole series instead of the series delimited by the range. ```> packageVersion('plotly')
[1] ‘4.10.0’```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to double-click on the plot to get the entire dataset. However, if I click on 'autoscale', I can get all of the data. When you define a range, it sets the scale to manual. By selecting 'autoscale', you're erasing those settings.

However, if you want to start as you have, and maintain the scale ratio, then use `scaleratio`, `constraintowards`, and add two invisible traces to account for the disparity in ranges (if we set ratio = 1, it's literal).

Add a line that has a y value that ranges between 30 and 44, aligned to `y`. Add another line that has a y value that ranges between 0 and 14, aligned to `y2`.

Check it out.

```
(chart2 <- plot_ly(x = df$OBS_DATE, 
                  y = df$Net_operating_surplus_to_value_added, 
                  type = 'scatter',  mode = 'lines', 
                  name = "Net operating surplus to value added (LHS)",
                  line = list(color = "#003299") ) %>% 
  add_trace(y = c(30, rep(44, nrow(df) - 1)), line = list(width = .0001),
            showlegend = F) %>%                      # <----- hidden trace
  add_trace(y = df$Met_retained_earnings_to_value_added, 
            name = "Met retained earnings to value added (RHS)", 
            line = list(color = "#FFB400" ), yaxis = "y2") %>% 
  add_trace(y = c(0, rep(14, nrow(df) - 1)), line = list(width = .0001),
            yaxis = "y2", showlegend = F) %>%        # <----- hidden trace
  layout(barmode = 'relative', barbase = 0, 
         xaxis = list(range = start_point), 
         yaxis = list(range = c(30, 44)),  
         yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", 
                       scaleratio = 1, scaleanchor = "y",
                       constraintoward = "bottom",
                       side = "right", range = c(0, 14))))
```

Now when you `autoscale`, you're going to maintain that same ratio you wanted to maintain.

Additionally, depending on what you're doing with this graph, you may want to have the two invisible traces called first, so they're on the bottom.

[image]